# use 'perf trace command' to a special thread with TSX abort

Tags: perf, intel-tsx

I try to use 'perf trace' command to trace tsx abort in a special thread. But I get errors with arguments. All command I think may be right and tried is below.

```
perf trace --pid 24265 --event tx-abort

perf trace --pid 24265 --event {tx-abort}

perf trace --pid 24265 --event {'tx-abort'}

perf trace --pid {24265} --event tx-abort

perf trace --pid {24265} --event {tx-abort}

perf trace --pid {24265} --event {'tx-abort'}

perf trace --pid {'24265'} --event tx-abort

perf trace --pid {'24265'} --event {tx-abort}

perf trace --pid {'24265'} --event {'tx-abort'}
```

> All error hins is 'Problems parsing the target to trace,check your options'.

Is there any way to let perf trace run as expected?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not the argument syntax, your first line should be just fine. First, check if `tx-abort` is listed by `perf list`, to see if it's generally supported on your system. Then the error may happen because the specified pid does not exist.

The TSX events are *PMU events*. As opposed to syscalls or tracepoints, not the individual event is instrumented in software, but there is a hardware counter within the Performance Monitoring Unit, that counts these events and triggers an interrupt after a certain amount of events. Taking a sample on each event is not typically feasible for PMU events. I suspect that is why it doesn't work for `perf trace`, which is originally intended for syscalls, even though the documentation a bit vague as to what type of events are supported.

Note I can reproduce that it doesn't work, but i get an "Invalid argument".  That PMU events are unsupported for `perf trace` is a a bit of speculation by me.

There is a broad documentation by Intel on [analyzing TSX with perf](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/05/03/intelr-transactional-synchronization-extensions-intelr-tsx-profiling-with-linux-0), which gives examples and explanation on how to use the the tx events with `perf record`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm sure that tx-abort is listed in `perf list` and pid exist. However, I still can't run perf trace as I used to try. I agree with your speculation that PMU events may not be supported by perf trace.